# How to return datatable using Take() using C#

Tags: c#, datatable, dataview, take

I have a function that returns a datatable, I added a code that will sort the datatable using dataview and should return Top 10 rows from a sorted dataview.

```
DataView dvDt = dtData.DefaultView;
dvDt.Sort = "Value DESC"
var vlist = dvDt.ToTable().AsEnumerable().Take(10);
```

I want to know how can I make sure I get the datatable as return item. How to convert "vlist" to datatable?

I use: C# and .net 3.5 framework.

Comment: Why do you want a datatable? what will you do with it that requires a table? As far as I know, there is no automated way to do this: you have to create your own table with the right columns and manually transfer each row (using .NewRow()/.AddRow()), but most of the time you don't need to do this: you can assign vlist as a datasource most anywhere as is.

Comment: Guys, I was working on an existing function that returns a datatable to the calling program. I just added the code to sort and get the top 10 records from the passed dataset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`DataTableExtensions.CopyToDataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189.aspx):

```
var table = vlist.CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: This will only work if `vlist` is an `IEnumerable<T> where T : DataRow`.

Comment: @Chris: Won't that be the case in this situation though, given the way that it's constructed?

Comment: @Jon: So it will. In the back of my mind, I knew you were going to end up being correct.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create an instance of a new `DataTable`, add the appropriate columns to it, and then iterate `vlist` and populate the data table via the [`NewRow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.newrow%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) method.  There are no built-in methods to do this for you.